# How to fix changing constraints and dynamic UITableviewCell height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uitextview

I am trying to have a UITableViewCell that can have or not an UIImageView displayed alongside with a UITextView. If I have only the text view, no problem, the cell change height accordingly. But when I try to update the height when the image changes size (I hide it by setting it to hidden = YES and updating the height constraint to a small value), the text needs to be updated to have to correct effect.

I might no be clear so here's the issue in action : 
[image: image size issue]

And the code :

```
 -(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

    CGFloat startHeight = self.textView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat calcHeight = [self.textView sizeThatFits:self.textView.frame.size].height;

    if (startHeight != calcHeight) {
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    }


}


    -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

            if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
                [textView resignFirstResponder];

            return YES;
            }


        - (IBAction)imgButtonPushed:(id)sender {

            //self.imageView.hidden = !self.imageView.hidden;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [self.tableView beginUpdates];
                if(self.imageView.hidden){
                    self.imageConstraintHeight.constant = 200;
                    self.imageView.hidden = NO;
                }else{
                    self.imageView.hidden = YES;
                    self.imageConstraintHeight.constant = 4;
                }

                [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
                [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

                [self.tableView endUpdates];

            });

        }
```

Does anyone knows how I could have a smooth and working effect ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Do you have constraints on the imageView to be anchored below the textview?

Comment: Yes, I think that all constraints a well set.

Comment: Personally, I would consider having two different cells (text only and test+image), and switch cells to add/remove the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a conflict with the name of my image view and the UITableViewCell image view. so I replace self.imageView to self.pictureView and everything works now.
I hope this will help someone some day ^^